# append a list into a list of list

Tags: python, list

```
grades =[["100", "90", "80"], ["1", "2"]]
a = list(1,2,3)
grades.append(a)
print (grades)
```

TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
Does anyone have a solution for that?

Thanks.

Comment: You are having error at `a = list(1,2,3)`. `list()` takes an iterable as argument, unlike you expect it. Try `a = list((1,2,3))`

Comment: `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple, which is an iterable. Other iterables in python are list, dict, set... Read more about python data types https://docs.python.org/2/library/datatypes.html

Comment: @akhilsp yea, `(1,2,3)` is a tuple, but those parantheses are of function call... Suggest you to get off of SO and stop insulting. Flagging your comment. Use `list((1,2,3))`

Answer (score 0):

What code were you trying? This should work fine:

```
a = [1,2]; b =[[1],[2,3]]
b.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. This is working fine for me.

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b =[[1],[2,3]]
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
[[1], [2, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
grades = [[1], [2,3]]
a = list((1,2,3))
grades.append(a)
```

You must use double parantheses, to group numbers into tuple. If you make one parantheses, it ia for function call.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
a = [1,2]
b =[[1],[2,3]]
b.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

Try with your interpreter, it's the basis of your learning.

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [[1], [2, 3]]
>>> b.append(a)
>>> b
[[1], [2, 3], [1, 2]]
```